# Looking to use AWS Glue marketplace Snowflake connector. Can load and push data easy, but want to call a stored procedure. Error 'unexpected "call"'

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

I have also not been able to find any documentation on the AWS Glue marketplace Snowflake connector. I know that underneath it is just the Snowflake Spark connector, so I have looked at some of that document, but not sure that it fully relates to the marketplace connector.

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-xdyn5il56d7a2?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=GlueStudio

I have seen options to use the regular connector, but would prefer using the marketplace connector I think.

Comment: How are you trying to call the stored procedure? If you use Script option in the AWS Glue job then you can run direct SQL and I believe there you can call the stored procedure.

Comment: From what I could find the direct SQL was limited to Redshift and something else. For Snowflake, from what I could find you have to use the Snowflake Marketplace connector or the Snowflake Spark Connector. I could be wrong but that is part of the issue, I am having trouble finding information about the usage.

Comment: Would [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Use-AWS-Glue-to-Call-Procedures-in-Snowflake) be an alternative?

Comment: Ya, that is the alternative, was just hoping to not have to manage 2 separate connections, so I guess I could switch completely to the regular connector. Seems like a waste to have the marketplace connector then.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this looking, I found the unfortunate answer that this is currently not supported thru the marketplace connector:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-snowflake-home.html

"This connector supports SELECT statement based queries when retrieving information (such as with the query parameter). Other kind of queries (such as SHOW, DESC, or DML statements) are not supported."